# Compiling sqlite amalgamation to get user authentication throws errors C2129 and C1083

Tags: c, sqlite

I want to compile the sqlite amalgamation to create a database which is protected by a password via user authentication.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html
And also the documentation by SQLite for the user_authentication: https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt

When I try to compile it without the extra compile-time option "-DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION" and without adding the other documents it works. When I try to compile it with I get the error C2129 at sqlite.c and error C1083 at userauth.c

In this directory are the following files:

- shell.c
- sqlite3.c
- sqlite3.h
- sqlite3ext.h
- sqlite3userauth.h
- userauth.c

```
cl -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION shell.c sqlite3.c userauth.c -Fesqlite3.exe
```

Following output:

```
shell.c
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.c(222878): error C2129: static function 'void sqlite3CryptFunc(sqlite3_context *,int,sqlite3_value **)' declared but not defined
sqlite3.c(16263): note: see declaration of 'sqlite3CryptFunc'
userauth.c
userauth.c(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqliteInt.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
```

In case there is something like C#'s db.SetPassword("MyPW") available in c, that would be perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I followed [...] the documentation by SQLite for the user_authentication: https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt

Well no, it doesn't look like you did.  Those docs say

> Activate the user authentication logic by including the
>   ext/userauth/userauth.c source code file in the build and adding the
>   -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION compile-time option. The ext/userauth/sqlite3userauth.h header file is available to
>   applications to define the interface.
>
> When using the SQLite amalgamation, it is sufficient to append the
>   ext/userauth/userauth.c source file onto the end of the amalgamation.

You are using the amalgamation, so you should *append* [the contents of] userauth.c to the amalgamation.  That is, copy its contents to the end of `sqlite3.c`.  From your directory listing and command line, it appears that you are instead attempting to build it as a separate source file, to be linked to the main one at the end.  That's not equivalent, and in particular, it differs with respect to the effect on the scope of `static` functions and variables, which is exactly what your compiler is complaining about.

It's unclear whether `-DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION` should also be used with the amalgamation.  A literal reading of the SQLite docs suggests not, but I would be inclined to guess that it actually is required either way if you want to enable the feature.

The error about the missing header is a little concerning, and it is possible that you will see it again.  If you do, it may be sufficient to simply remove or comment out the corresponding `#include` directive, as all the needed declarations from that header, which is among the main sources, should already be included in the amalgamation.

Comment: Looking [at the repository source of userauth.c](https://sqlite.org/src/artifact/f81aa5a3ecacf406), the whole files is in a conditional dependent on `SQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION` being set, so that probably **should** be defined. However, the contents of `sqliteInt.h` is already present in the amalgamation, so OP should just be able to delete the `#include` line (after appending userauth.c to the amalgamation). I've not tested this, though!

Comment: Thank you, both problems solved by appending the code!

Comment: That's an entirely separate questions, @Duco, and you're much more likely to get helpful answers if you pose it as one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your detailed answer. I am getting another error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647781/how-to-activate-the-user-authentication-logic-of-sqlite3-in-c). Can you please take a look?