# How to activate the user authentication logic of sqlite3 in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite, gcc, qt-creator, mingw32

I am trying to utilize user authentication on sqlite3 for my c++ project. I have followed the steps explained in [here](https://www.sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/userauth/user-auth.txt&ci=24b0f66ac611e26f). I have added `sqlite3userauth.h` into the end of `sqlite3.h` and `userauth.c` into the end of `sqlite3.c` and included `#include "sqlite3.h"` in my code. But now my code does not recognize any of the new functions such as `sqlite3_user_add`. Also, I have tried to compile `shell.c` using the following command `gcc -o sqlite3Exe shell.c sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread` but I got this error:

> sqlite3.c:230543:11: fatal error: sqliteInt.h: No such file or
> directory  # include "sqliteInt.h"
> compilation terminated.

I tried to comment that line but then I got another error:

> sqlite3.c:230730:3: error: too few arguments to function
> 'sqlite3ExpirePreparedStatements'
> sqlite3ExpirePreparedStatements(db);

that line is referring to :

```
   sqlite3ExpirePreparedStatements(db);
```

I haven't made any changes on the main code and followed the tips given by the official website but it seems like it doesn't work. Can you please guide me through this? I am using QT and trying to create a password-protected database interface.

Here are some parts of my code:

1. project.pro (I have added `sqlite3` and compiler flags this way) :

   SOURCES += 
   sqlite/sqlite3.c 
   ...

   HEADERS +=
   sqlite/sqlite3.h 
   ...

   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread

this is part of my `sqlite3.h` file (it shows where have I added the codes of `sqlite3userauth.h`):

```
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}  /* end of the 'extern "C"' block */
#endif

#endif /* _FTS5_H */

/******** End of fts5.h *********/
/*
** 2014-09-08
**
** The author disclaims copyright to this source code.  In place of
** a legal notice, here is a blessing:
**
**    May you do good and not evil.
**    May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
**    May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
**
*************************************************************************
...
```

and this one is part of my `sqlite3.c` file ( this shows where have I added the codes of `userauth.c` ):

```
...
#if __LINE__!=230511
#undef SQLITE_SOURCE_ID
#define SQLITE_SOURCE_ID      "2020-08-14 13:23:32 fca8dc8b578f215a969cd899336378966156154710873e68b3d9ac5881b0alt2"
#endif
/* Return the source-id for this library */
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_sourceid(void){ return SQLITE_SOURCE_ID; }
/************************** End of sqlite3.c ******************************/
/*
** 2014-09-08
**
** The author disclaims copyright to this source code.  In place of
** a legal notice, here is a blessing:
**
**    May you do good and not evil.
**    May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
**    May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
**
*************************************************************************
**
** This file contains the bulk of the implementation of the
** user-authentication extension feature.  Some parts of the user-
** authentication code are contained within the SQLite core (in the
** src/ subdirectory of the main source code tree) but those parts
** that could reasonable be separated out are moved into this file.
**
...
```

And here this is my `dbmanager.cpp` file where I utilize `sqlite3`:

```
    extern "C"{
    #include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"
    }
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    DBmanager::DBmanager(string dbAdd)
    {
        if(exists(dbAdd)){
            cout<<dbAdd<<" file already exists"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<dbAdd<<" file doesn't exist and will be created for the first time"<<endl;
        }
        this->dbAdd=dbAdd;
    
    
        int rc;
        rc = sqlite3_open(this->dbAdd.c_str(), &this->db);
        sqlite3_user_add(db,"Admin","Admin",2,1); // this is the line that throws the exceptions that I have mentioned below.
    if( rc ) {
            cout<<"Can't open database: "<< sqlite3_errmsg(this->db)<<endl;
            return;
        } else {
            cout<<"Opened database successfully"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Update:

1. I have added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread` into my `.pro` file. Now, QtCreator detects functions such as `sqlite3_user_add` but when I try to compile my project it gives the following error:

> undefined reference to `sqlite3_user_add'

> :-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Do you link with `-lsqlite3`? Maybe you could try to create a small example so that we can reproduce the errors you get?

Comment: @AndreasDM  I am not using `sqlite3` as a library. Instead, I add `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` into my project and include `sqlite3.h` in my cpp file. It works this way if I don't use authentication but crashes when I use the authentication-related functions. I will try to add a code.

Comment: @AndreasDM I have updated my post by adding parts of my code. Please take a look.

Answer (score -2):

Error which you attached above , it's an Compilaiton error .
Try to add the mysql flag, which help in linking your client library

```
eg: g++ youSqlCode.cpp -o b lmysqlcppconn
```

Comment: I'm not using `mysql`; I am using `sqlite` on `Qtcreator`. Where should I add this line? I am trying to build my application on `QT`, the command line command that I have posted above is to check if it is working or not. The main problem is that QT doesn't recognize the functions of user authentication.

Comment: This a compilation error for not able to detecting header file 
There are two approaches ->
1. include header file lib form your compiler setting of QT
2. Add the flag which is mentioned above in the .pro file or Qmake file depends you either you are using cmake for project or Qt configurations.
eg. 
SOURCES += main.cpp2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

Comment: _"it's an linking error"_ No it isn't. And SqlLite has nothing whatsoever to do with MySQL, nor the MySQL C++ connector. Don't just randomly guess, Omesh.

Comment: @omeshsharma I have added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread` into my .pro file. Now, `QtCreator` detects functions such as `sqlite3_user_add` but when I try to compile my project it gives following error: "undefined reference to `sqlite3_user_add'".

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings please see the Question properly , he have error "no such a file or directory " i just try to relate the problem with mysql because i used it . for the same case in sqllite their will be a separate package config name don't get confuse .

Comment: @NewUser  You need to adjust your linker flags to link in the sqlite3 library. Libraries are usually installed in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64

Alternatively, you can copy the sqlite3.c file to your project directory and compile it as part of the g++ command:

Comment: @omeshsharma _"please see the Question properly , he have error "no such a file or directory"_  ... which isn't a linker error. It's a compilation error about a header. Your answer does not address the problem. _"for the same case in sqllite their will be a separate package config name don't get confuse"_ No, it's a completely different problem.

Comment: Dear @AsteroidsWithWings Compilation error , that's true , But sqllite library needs the flags which will tells the compiler where is this package .o file have been written which is addressed during linking about to start, still you are confuse.

Comment: Dear  @AsteroidsWithWings and @omeshsharma, I am copying and compiling `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` to my project and compile it within my project. I have just added parts of my code in the question.

Comment: @NewUser add this flag and see : -lsqlite3 at the same .pro file where you add -lpthread

Comment: @omeshsharma No it didn't work. I am compiling `sqlite3.c` inside my project you can see my source code on my post.

Comment: @NewUser QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread  
 -lsqlite3 into my .pro file

Comment: @NewUser when you uses sqlite3_user_add make sure you have included the name space if there any.